# What is the general formal definition of ordinal definable sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

The following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set) article about OD sets, mentions the informal definition of ordinal definable sets, yet it says that it cannot be captured formally in first order logic. I just want to make sure that I've got the correct idea.

Is the following the full formal definition of ordinal definable sets, albeit not in first order logic.

$x \text { is ordinal definable in } T  \iff \\\exists \alpha_1,..,\alpha_n, \varphi: T \vdash (\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n \text{ are ordinals } \wedge \forall y [y=x \leftrightarrow \varphi(y,\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n)])$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not correct - **you're mixing up objects/models and theories**.

Ordinal definability is with respect to a model, not a theory: specifically, given an $\{\in\}$-structure $M$ *(which it's convenient to assume satisfies some weak set theory so basic definitions play well)*, there is an external subset $OD^M\subseteq M$ given by $$OD^M=\{u\in M: \exists \alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in Ord^M, \varphi\in Formula  (M\models\forall x(\varphi(x,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)\iff x=u))\}.$$ An element $u$ of $M$ is *ordinal definable in $M$* iff $u\in OD^M$.

(Incidentally we could make do with a single ordinal - as long as $M$ satisfies *very* weak closure properties, every finite tuple of ordinals in $M$ is appropriately definable from a single ordinal in $M$.)

---

Note that $u$ and $\alpha$ need not be parameter-freely definable in $M$, so it wouldn't even make sense to ask what a *theory* thinks about them. (What do I mean by this? Well, when we say "ZFC thinks that the cofinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable" we're really talking about what ZFC proves about a *specific formula*, and the point is that "the continuum in the sense of $M$" is uniformly parameter-freely definable in $M$. More generally, if $M\models$ ZFC, $u\in M$, and $u$ is parameter-freely definable in $M$ via a forula $\psi(x)$ such that ZFC proves that exactly one thing satisfies $\psi$ we can ask what ZFC proves about $\psi$. But this conflation crucially relies on the object we care about being parameter-freely definable in the particular model in question, and that doesn't apply to either arbitrary $M$-ordinals or arbitrary $M$-OD sets in general.

Comment: I think the definition is missing to state that $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n $ are ordinals. I also do not understand what you mean by saying that you considered a single ordinal? clearly $\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n$ is a tuple of ordinals. Also I don't understand your notes about $u$ and $\alpha$ being parameter free, at least for the case of $u$ it is not parameter free, it has $n$ many parameters, the alpha's. I must be missing something?

Comment: So $ u \text { is ordinal definable in } M \iff \exists \text{ ordinals } \alpha_1,..,\alpha_n [\exists \varphi \ M \models \forall x (x=u \iff \varphi(x,\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n))] $.

Comment: @Zuhair I've edited: the "single ordinal" bit was leftover from a slightly different writeup; that the $\alpha_i$s were ordinals and the $\varphi$ a formula I took to be implicit, but I've clarified that; and I've expanded on the definability bit (the only point about that is explaining why your theory-based approach really can't work here).

Comment: @Is it the case that every parameter free definable set is also ordinal definable one!

Comment: @Zuhair Yes, of course - if you're definable without any parameters at all, you're definable with ordinal parameters.